# User profile pages broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

Going to anyone's profile on MSE, SO or Super User (didn't try others) results in an error page.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Comment: Reproduced on Physics, Astronomy, and Worldbuilding, as well as their meta sites.

Comment: Every site from what I can work out

Comment: Also, the mobile app is down (both Android and iOS)

Comment: Reproduced on, like, fifteen of the sites I've got an account on (I don't remember which, but they were picked roughly randomly)

Comment: I just got this on RPG on one user, but not on the next one. However, trying it again just now with the same two users to see if there's a correlation with the different behaviour, I'm getting it with both (and all the rest, too), so I can probably blame the brief differences on caching.

Comment: This is occurring to me on Raspberry Pi StackExchange, on the main site and the meta site.

Comment: It's fixed now.

Comment: Seems to be fixed now.

Comment: Voting to close as "no repro" since the pages are back now

Comment: @Ferrybig: Let's wait to see how long they work for. It could be unstable.

Comment: We broke it, we're fixing it, someone will post an answer soon.

Comment: @Haney: lol, good, and thanks (in that order) #commaspliceignored

Comment: @Ferrybig: No sense closing as no repro if it was *fixed*, only if it was *nullified by unrelated events*.

Comment: Agree with @Nathan, the no-repro is over used here way too much. It's meant for OLD bugs that were never fixed, and can't be reproduced any more hence can't be fixed any more.

Comment: @closevoters why close it? If this is closed, couldn’t we close **every** solved bug report as no reproduce?

Comment: Indeed; that's what [tag:status-completed] is for. The "can no longer reproduce" is something different (albeit, admittedly, on meta, subtly so)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. We made a change to our SQL server configuration that caused our logins to fail, which meant the data driving our sites was inaccessible (thus the errors). We've fixed that error and things should now be working properly. Sorry for the inconvenience!

A quote from Greg Bray, Site Reliability Engineer:

> The ny-sql01 server was recently replaced, and we just tried adding it to the read only routing list using a new feature in opserver. We thought that feature failed, but it seems to have worked and uncovered a missing login/permissions issue (connections were failing to connect). The fix was to remove the new server from the read only routing list until we can figure out why the connections were failing.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition but of course! :)

Answer (score -6):

Yes, the Stack Exchange API started having issues around 16:40 UTC (4:40pm). Reported issues include:

- Inability to load user profiles
- Pages not loading in the iOS/Android apps

Features that still work include:

- Posting questions/answers from the desktop/mobile sites
- Global inbox notifications
- Push notifications on iOS devices

**Edit:** Issues seem to have been temporary. As of 16:51 UTC (4:51pm), the site appears to be functioning normally.

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: can't you just reproduce the SO Code? Class a{public a(){a anA = new a();}} ?